# Collection typed parameters hidden on other methods in generic Interface in Java

Tags: java, generics

Say I've an interface "Generic" -

```
public interface Generic<T> {
    public T echo(T input); 
    public List<String> hello();    
}
```

And an implementation class say `GenericImpl` with any trivial implementation. Now, when I create an instance of `Generic` and invoke `hello`, it returns me a `List` and not a `List<String>` -

```
 Generic g1 = new GenericImpl();
 for (String msg : g1.hello()) {  // Gives compilation error : 
  // Type mismatch, cannot convert from element type Object to String
 ...
```

Even in eclipse, when I hover on `g1.hello`, it shows me the return type as `List` and not `List<String>`.

This does not happen if I use a normal interface (without generic `<T>` ). Any suggestions on how to make it work / why does it happen ?

Comment: Put in the code for GenericImpl, that might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with raw types. First, a [definition](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

> To facilitate interfacing with non-generic legacy code, **it is possible
>   to use as a type the erasure (§4.6) of a parameterized type (§4.5) or
>   the erasure of an array type (§10.1) whose element type is a
>   parameterized type. Such a type is called a raw type.**

You are using such a raw type here

```
Generic g1 = new GenericImpl();
```

since `Generic` has no type argument. Then the JLS also states

> **The type of a** constructor (§8.8), **instance method** (§8.4, §9.4), or
>   non-static field (§8.3) M **of a raw type C** that is not inherited from
>   its superclasses or superinterfaces **is the raw type that corresponds
>   to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to
>   C.**

Therefore, when using the raw type `Generic`, the `hello()` method has a return type of `List` which is the erasure of `List<String>`. As such, the return type of `List#iterator()` is `Iterator` and the return type of `Iterator#next()` is `Object`, a type which cannot be converted to `String`.

You will need to use a type argument for your `g1`'s type declaration so that it is not considered a variable of a raw type.

Answer (score 3):

You have to define the interface as generic (with a type).

```
Generic<YourGenericType> g1 = new GenericImpl();
```

By ommitting the generic definition, it will be considered a "raw type". Raw types will return `Objects` instead. More information on raw types can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html).

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Generic<Integer> obj = new GenericImpl();
        System.out.println(obj.echo(5));
        for(String s : obj.hello()){
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
}

interface Generic<T> {
    public T echo(T input); 
    public List<String> hello();    
}

class GenericImpl implements Generic<Integer> {
    @Override
    public Integer echo(Integer input) {
        return input;
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> hello() {
        return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("lala", "lolo"));
    }   
}
```

Output:

> 5
>   lala
>   lolo

Comment: Ah I see. However, in my original code, I'm using a List<Generic> generics, and then calling the hello method on each of them. i.e. -
    for (Generic generic : generics) {
        for (String msg : generic.hello()) { 
            etc.

So this is still a problem

Comment: Your code literally states `Generic g1 = new GenericImpl();`. Your object is defined as a raw type of `Generic`. You have to turn it into a generic type, using the generic definition.